# Setting a textbox text in usercontrol from page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which contains a textbox. I now want to add variable to that user control, lets call it Text, which will populate the textbox with the value passed in. I thought this could be done in the "set" of the variable in the code behind of the user control.

```
public string Text
{
    get {}
    set
    {
        txtBox.Text = value;
    }
}
```

txtBox is the ID of the textbox within the usercontrol. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

**Edit**
The problem I suspect is that I am setting the text value in the Page_Load of the page hosting the user control. Where should I be setting this value?

Comment: No its not. Can't for the life of me figure out why. Event stripped my usercontrol down to nothing but a textbox and still nothing.

Comment: What's actually in the getter for this property? It's not blank, because that wouldn't compile.

Comment: I created a simple usercontrol with textbox same as you said, and has put the same code which you posted (returning textbox value in get) and assigned value in page_load and it worked fine. why dont you try with simple web app and simple usercontrol with textbox?

Comment: I hope viewstate is enabled for your page/control

Comment: Please post the code of the page (html)

Comment: Something went horribly wrong with IIS. Not entirely sure what it was but basically it was keeping a cache of the page so any changes I made did not reflect. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that `txtBox` is null then I can suggest you the following:

If you're creating a user control dynamically then don't forget to add it to the page's control tree BEFORE (implicitly or explicitly) accessing its child controls. Otherwise all these child controls will remain uninitialized:

```
MyUserControl ctrl = (MyUserControl )Page.LoadControl("~/MyUserControl.ascx");
base.Controls.Add(ctrl);

ctrl.Text = "some value";
```

If your user control is declared in the page's markup then don't forget to register using the `Register` directive with the "Src" property set to location of your user control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="controls" TagName="MyUserControl" 
    Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" %>

<controls:MyUserControl id="ctrl1" Text="some value" runat="server" />
```

Registering the user control using the following technique WILL NOT work (not the case if all child controls are created dynamically. But then you don't need a user control - you just need a class derived from the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.aspx) class):

```
<%-- Will not work for user controls --%>
<%@ Register Assembly="MyControlsAssembly.Shell" Namespace="MyControls" 
    TagPrefix="controls" %>
```

Hope this will help you.